# where is the remainder stored after i complete the division?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm just learning assembly language and I'm having trouble figuring out where my remainder is stored after I divide.

I believe the remainder is stored in one of the registers but I do not know which one or how to print it to the screen.

```
mov     eax, number1
xor     edx, edx
div     number2
call    WriteDec
call    CrLf
```

the above code prints the quotient but does not print the remainder.

Comment: read the manual: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/DIV.html

Comment: @PeterCordes I have Assembly Language for x86 Processors by Kip Irvine and I've read the chapters regarding both multiplication and division, I am not seeing the answer that I need, could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Read Intel's manuals, especially the volume 2 manual which documents exactly what each instruction does, any time you want more detail about a specific instruction.  My first comment linked an HTML extract of the relevant entry, did you not look at it?

Comment: @PeterCordes yes I read it, I see that the remainder is stored in the edx register, now I just need to print that and I will go back to the manual to see how to print a register to the screen.

Comment: There's no instruction for that, and VGA hardware isn't part of the CPU, so you won't find anything like that in Intel's manual.  Look at the docs for OS system calls if you want to print stuff.  Or since you're using Irvine32, `mov eax, edx` / `call WriteDec`, because it takes an arg in EAX.  (That's why it prints the quotient when you call it after `div`.)

Answer (score 6):

As [documented](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_72.html) in the manual, a 32 bit `div` stores the quotient in `eax` and the remainder in `edx`.

It is generally a good idea to read the manual on every instruction you want to use.